# Using Moving-average smoothing in forecast package

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, smoothing

I tried to use the non-centred moving average, that means just using past values by setting the option centre  = FALSE, but unfortunately you get the centred results.
Can anyone detect the failure here in the ma function?

> getAnywhere(ma)
>       A single object matching ‘ma’ was found
>       It was found in the following places
>         package:forecast
>         namespace:forecast
>       with value

```
function (x, order, centre = TRUE) 
{
    tt <- 1:length(x)
    if (order%%2) {
        temp1 <- ts(ksmooth(tt, x, x.points = tt, bandwidth = order - 
            1)$y)
            j <- trunc(order/2)
            temp1[c(1:j, length(x) - (1:j) + 1)] <- NA
        }
        else {
            temp1 <- ts(ksmooth(tt, x, x.points = tt + 0.5, bandwidth = order - 
                1)$y)
            j <- trunc(order/2)
            temp1[c(1:(j - 1), length(x) - (1:j) + 1)] <- NA
            if (centre) {
                temp2 <- ksmooth(tt, x, x.points = tt - 0.5, bandwidth = order - 
                    1)$y
            temp2[c(1:j, length(x) - (1:(j - 1)) + 1)] <- NA
            temp1 <- ts((temp1 + temp2)/2)
        }
    }
    tsp(temp1) <- tsp(x)
    return(temp1)
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding an error in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-centred MA is not the same as a one-sided MA. See https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6/2 to learn about moving averages.

A non-centred MA is still two-sided, but for even values of `order` it is not centered on an observation.

If you want a one-sided moving average, then set `centre=FALSE` and shift the time attribute by half of `order`.